Is it rude for me to say to my grandma, "you are easy on the eyes"?
Collins dictionary says

easy on the eye informal: pleasant to look at; attractive, esp sexually

I have just watched "Fly Me to the Moon".
In the film, a woman said to her friend about a man, "he is easy on the eyes". There is a sexual intention in that scene.
I think we can definitely say that to our friends or people we want to flirt, but I am not sure if we can say that to one we need to show respect like our grandma or grandpa.
Is it rude for me to say to my grandma, "you are easy on the eyes"?
I hope this is not an opinion-based question because we learners want to know if it is polite or suitable to say this to some people.

I don't understand. The definition tells you it is a compliment for someone you find [sexually] attractive, you say "easy on the eyes"  is appropriate if you are flirting. You can tell a friend that there's someone pretty, beautiful, stunning, "hot", sexy,  and/or easy on the eyes. Yet you think it might be OK to say this to your own grandmother? Why?  Just be careful never to say this about an underage child to a native speaker or someone who is proficient in English!

people we want to flirt with.

Yes, this is not something you would normally say to your grandmother. "Easy on the eyes" is a slang term meaning "pretty" or "handsome". It has a certain amount of sexual or romantic connotation. You might say to a girl that you are taking on a date, "You are easy on the eyes." More likely you would say it about someone that you would like to have a romantic or sexual relationship with when talking to some third party. Like, "George is certainly easy on the eyes. I hope he asks me out."
But it would be inappropriate to say to your grandmother. It would be implying that you have romantic or sexual desire for your grandmother, which, to my mind anyway, would be somewhere between weird and gross. You MIGHT say this if your grandmother is relatively young and if she has just dressed up to go on a date. Like if you're 15 years old and your grandmother is 40, you might possibly say, "Wow grandma, that dress you put on for the date looks really pretty. You are really easy on the eyes." Possible, but still pushing it, I think.

I don't think it's possible for a grandmother only 25 years older than you, though, especially in modern times. Because it means that on average, both your parents and grandparents gave birth at age 12.5, which is quite early, to say the least.

@LukeL I was trying to construct an extreme case. Is it POSSIBLE for a woman to have a baby at age 12? Yes. Is it very rare? Certainly. If it makes you feel better, say you're 15 and your grandmother is 45, so each had a child at 15. Still unlikely, but more realistic.

Yeah, that's better. I really don't think there had ever been a case where two consecutive generations had birth at age 12. On the other hand, giving birth at age 15, although still a bit too early, is much more reasonable and realistic.

I don't know your grandmother, but "easy on the eyes" is nearly always used to mean "good-looking, attractive, sexy".  Are you saying that she is the sort of person that men would stare at and fantasise about?
I wouldn't use "you are easy on the eyes" to anyone.  And it would normally be part of a sentence "He's easy on the eyes, but .... (no brain, bad personality etc)"
